# One to one chat PHP

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I am trying to develop a one to one chat. I want the users to only be able to see messages from the sender i.e the sender only sees the messages from himself and the receive but the query fails to run. I am able to see all the messages present in the database

```
public function getMessages() {

 $messages = array();
 $query = <<<QUERY
    SELECT 
      `chat`.`message`, 
      `chat`.`sent_on`,
      `user1`.`id`, 
      `user1`.`first_name`
    FROM `user1`
    JOIN `chat`
      ON `chat`.`user_id` = `user1`.`id` AND `chat`.`rec_id`=$recid
    ORDER BY `sent_on`
  QUERY;
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: no question here?

Comment: `You're unable to solve.` **But What.????**

Comment: This question looks a lot like [Creating One To One Chat in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43447291/1016716) tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `userId` in your query like this:

```
public function getMessages($userId) {

  $messages = array();
  $query = <<<QUERY
     SELECT 
       `chat`.`message`, 
       `chat`.`sent_on`,
       `user1`.`id`, 
       `user1`.`first_name`
     FROM `user1`
     JOIN `chat`
       ON `chat`.`user_id` = `user1`.`id` AND `chat`.`rec_id`=$recid
     WHERE `user1`.`id` = {$userId}
     ORDER BY `sent_on`
   QUERY;
```